# Awk to combine field from 2 files

Tags: awk

I would like to combine 2 files to combine some fields from each.

File1:

```
24sessions|!24sessions
27upng|!upng
2dehands.be|!2dehands
2manc|!uom
2ememain.be|!2ememain
```

File2:

```
Research|Academic|!uoftlib
RRRR|AAAAAA|!uom
Research|Academic|!upng
Research|Academic|!ur
```

I've tried this Awk but the array building is not right:

```
awk ' BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" } NR==FNR{check[$0];next} { $3 in check; print $0, check[$0] } ' file1.txt file2.txt  >out1.txt
```

This is the desired output:

Out1:

```
Research|Academic|!upng__27upng
RRRR|AAAAAA|!uom__2manc
```

Please note the delimiter between the last 2 fields is "__" not "|"

Comment: There are no strings `Tech` or `Startups` in any of the two files

Comment: Fixed in OP. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fixing a little bit your own command :

```
awk ' BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" } NR==FNR{check[$2]=$1;next}$3 in check{print $0 "_" check[$3] } ' file1.txt file2.txt > out1.txt
```

What was wrong ? You did't store the first column of first file inside the `check` array and you used wrong keys when inserting and retrieving values.